# How do I integrate TFS with Active Directory(AD)

Tags: amazon-web-services, tfs, active-directory

I have TFS installation on one server and AD on another, both of which are hosted on AWS. I am unable to integrate TFS so as to authenticate with AD server

Comment: Did you join the TFS application tier server to the domain? That's all that's required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to join the server which installs TFS to AD. You could refer to [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/join_windows_instance.html) about how to manually join a Windows instance to a Simple AD or AWS Managed Microsoft AD directory:

> To manually join an existing Amazon EC2 Windows instance to a Simple
>   AD or AWS Directory Service for Microsoft Active Directory directory,
>   the instance must be launched as specified in [Seamlessly Join a
>   Windows EC2 Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/launching_instance.html):
>
> 1. Connect to the instance using any Remote Desktop Protocol client.
> 2. Open the TCP/IPv4 properties dialog box on the instance.
> 3. (Optional) Select **Use the following DNS server addresses**, change the **Preferred DNS server** and **Alternate DNS server** addresses to the IP
>      addresses of the AWS Directory Service-provided DNS servers, and
>      choose **OK**.
> 4. Open the **System Properties** dialog box for the instance, select the **Computer Name** tab, and choose **Change**.
> 5. In the **Member of** field, select **Domain**, enter the fully-qualified name of your AWS Directory Service directory, and choose **OK**.
> 6. When prompted for the name and password for the domain administrator, enter the username and password of an account that has
>      domain join privileges. For more information about delegating these
>      privileges, see [Delegate Directory Join Privileges for AWS Managed
>      Microsoft AD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/directory_join_privileges.html).
> 7. After you receive the message welcoming you to the domain, restart the instance to have the changes take effect.